# Stata: Observation-pairwise calculation

Tags: loops, stata

```
input X group
21 1
62 1
98 1
12 2
87 2
end
```

Now I try to calculate a measure as follows:

```
$$ \sum_{g} \left | X_{ig}-X_{jg} \right | $$
```

,where $i$ or $j$ ($i \neq j$) indexes an observation. g corresponds to the group variable (here, 1 and 2)

How to calculate this number using loops?

Comment: Your latex code is not working properly. Please edit that.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a Gini mean difference, apart from a scaling factor. There are numerous user-written commands already in this territory. There is (unusually) a summary within the Stata manual at [R] inequality.

In addition, this is related to the second L-moment. See the `lmoments` command from SSC.

You need *not* calculate this through a double loop over indexes. It collapses to a linear combination of the order statistics.

LATER: See David's 1998 paper which is open-access at

https://doi.org/10.1214/ss/1028905831